# product filters with AND condition in eloquent laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I am working around with pivot table in Laravel Eloquent which is great but I am stuck in a point where I am unable to find the solution.
I have three tables shown **below**

### ## plant ##

### id    |    name

1    |    plant_1
2    |    plant_2
3    |    plant_3

### seasons

### **id**    |    **season_name**

1    |    Summer
2    |    Winter
3    |    Mid-Summer

### plant_to_season

### **id**    |    **plant_id**    |    **season_id**

1         |    1        |    1
2         |    2        |    2
3         |    3        |    2
4         |    3        |    3

Now if I apply filters like

```
$filters = array(1,2,3);
\App\Plant::with(['seasons' => function($query) use ($filters) {
              return $query->wherein('seasons.id', $filters);
          }])->groupBy('id')->get();
```

This code returns me all three plants. But what I actually want is those plants which exactly have these 3 given filters.
I have searched everywhere from **laravel documentation** to **Stackoverflow** but there is no help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more tricky than expected, You should def use the `whereHas` method instead of `with` and then loop through your filters: Here is my suggestion on how to solve this, it works, but maybe there is a shorter solution:

```
$filters = array(1,2,3);
  $outquery = \App\Plant::where('id','>',1);
  foreach( $filters as $filter){
    $outquery = $outquery->whereHas('seasons', function($query) use ($filter){
              $query->where('id','=',$filter);
          });
  }
  return $outquery->get();
```

Comment: Well,I have gone through all MySql documents and it is clear that we cannot use AND operation in single column instead, we should use WHEREIN clause.

Comment: @HusnainAhmed : Did you try my proposed solution?

Comment: Yes, I tried your proposed solution which is correct to some extend but I used it with `whereIn('id', $filters);`

Comment: With `whereIn` you won't accomplish, what you are looking for. You want all Plants that contain all of your filters and not the ones that have 1 or 2 of your filters.